# How to unmarshal a non-hierarchical relationship with Java's JAXB library?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm attempting to unmarshal the following XML with Java's JAXB library.

```
<message name="GetAllRoutesSoapIn">
  <part name="parameters" element="GetAllRoutes"/>
</message>

...

<operation name="GetAllRoutes">
  <input message="GetAllRoutesSoapIn"/>
</operation>
```

It's easy enough to unmarshal this file hierarchically: A Message has many Parts, an Operation has an Input. But I'm having trouble establishing a relationship between an input and a message.

I'd like the unmarshalled `Input` class to have a field of type `Message` instead of type `String`.

**Input Class**

```
@XmlType
public class Input extends AbstractElement {

// @XmlAttribute
// private String message; 

// Not sure how to implement this. XMLAdapter?
private Message message;

protected Input () {}

...
```

My initial idea was to create a custom Message XMLAdapter and annotate both the Message class, and Input's Message property with a @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MessageAdapter.class). I'd keep a static collection of all instantiated Messages on the Adaptor class. The Messages instantiated from the proper xml element "message" would be collected, and searched through when the adapter attempted to unmarshal a Message from the input's message attribute. Came close to working but I can't get the adapter to fire for the input class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of relationship is mapped with `@XmlID` (on a field/property that uniquely identifies the object) and `XmlIDREF` (on the reference to that object.  Note that the referenced object must also be referenced by another object through what your are calling a hierarchy relationship.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how XmlID and XmlIDREF can bind objects of different types, joining on arbitrary attributes.

Comment: Yep, I got that working. Thanks. I've got another question similar to this but with namespace prefixes in the input's message attribute. I'll post a separate thread.